# Suppose that A and B are vectors so that A+2B = A-2B have the same magnitude. Why do A and B have to be orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation, orthogonality

Suppose that **A** and **B** are vectors so that **A**+2**B** and **A**-2**B** have the same magnitude. Explain why **A** and **B** are orthogonal.

Comment: Use the scalar product.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: If you say $A+2B=A-2B$, then that's a lot stronger than the two having the same magnitude. It means they are _equal_.

Comment: You should correct the statement. You should *either* say $\|\mathbf A + 2\mathbf B\| = \|\mathbf A - 2\mathbf B\|$ *or* you should replace the equals sign with the word "and."

Comment: @TedShifrin Well spotted. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\lVert\mathbf{A}+2\mathbf{B}\rVert^2=(\mathbf{A}+2\mathbf{B})\cdot(\mathbf{A}+2\mathbf{B})=\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of norm in terms of dot product and cancel similar terms to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

$A+2B$ and $A-2B$ are diagonals of a parallelogram with sides $|A|$ and $|2B|.$ Since the diagonals are equal, it is a rectangle. Also the vectors A and B are orthogonal.

Comment: +1. Several properties of vectors and quadrilaterals are considered by the [Parallelogram rule (law)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).